# Print an array with an input in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, input

I want to print an array using an input. This is an example of what I'm trying to do with a lot less arrays:

```
# Input
x = input()

# Array
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
c = [2, 3, 4]
d = [1, 2, 3]
#Print Array
print(x)
```

If someone is to input b it would print:

```
'b'
```

Instead of:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is there anyway I can fix this without using an if statement for every array?

Comment: Use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary data type:

```
# Input
x = input()

# Array
arraysByLetter = {}
arraysByLetter['b'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arraysByLetter['c'] = [2, 3, 4]
arraysByLetter['d'] = [1, 2, 3]

# Print Array
print(arraysByLetter[x])
```